# How can I filter the Persian alphabet in PHP for Joomla 4?

Tags: php, joomla-4.x, filter

Before anything, I must say this code works as well for the English language, but in Persian it never works.

I use this code on **model/celebrities.php**.
This code shows my frontend model:

```
class AvisamoviedbModelCelebrities extends ListModel
{

    protected function populateState($ordering = null, $direction = null)
    {
        $app     = Factory::getApplication('site');
        $params = $app->getParams();
        $this->setState('list.start', $app->input->get('limitstart',0,'unit'));
        $limit  = $params->get('celebrities_limit');
        $this->setState('list.limit', $limit);
    }
    /**
     * Method to get a JDatabaseQuery object for retrieving the data set from a database.
     *
     * @return  JDatabaseQuery   A JDatabaseQuery object to retrieve the data set.
     *
     * @since   1.0.0
     */
    public function getListQuery($overrideLimits = false)
    {
        if (Factory::getApplication()->isClient('site')) {
            // Get Params
            $app             = Factory::getApplication();
            $params           = $app->getMenu()->getActive()->getParams(); // get the active item
            $order_by         = $params->get('order_by', '');
            $celebrity_type = $params->get('celebrities_type', '');
            $gender         = $params->get('gender', '');
        }

        $inputs = Factory::getApplication()->input;
        $alphaindex = $inputs->get('alphaindex', '', 'WORD');

        //for celebrities per page limit
        $cparams = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_avisamoviedb');
        $start     = $app->input->get('start', 0, 'INT');
        $limit   = $cparams->get('celebrities_limit');

        $db = $this->getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);


        $query->select(array('a.*'));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__avisamoviedb_celebrities', 'a'));

        if (Factory::getApplication()->isClient('site')) {

            if ($alphaindex) {
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.title') . " LIKE " . $db->quote(($alphaindex) . '%'));
            }

            $query->where($db->quoteName('a.published') . " = " . $db->quote('1'));
            $query->setLimit($limit, $start);

            if ($order_by == 'desc') {
                $query->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' DESC');
            } elseif ($order_by == 'asc') {
                $query->order($db->quoteName('a.created') . ' ASC');
            } elseif ($order_by == 'featured') {
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.featured') . ' = 1');
                $query->order($db->quoteName('a.ordering') . ' DESC');
            } else {
                $query->order($db->quoteName('a.ordering') . ' DESC');
            }

            if ($celebrity_type == 'actors') {
                $query->where('a.celebrity_type in (' . $db->quote('actor') . ',' . $db->quote('both') . ')');
            } elseif ($celebrity_type == 'directors') {
                $query->where('a.celebrity_type in (' . $db->quote('director') . ',' . $db->quote('both') . ')');
            }

            if ($gender == 'male') {
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.gender') . ' = ' . $db->quote('male'));
            } elseif ($gender == 'female') {
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.gender') . ' = ' . $db->quote('female'));
            } elseif ($gender == 'others') {
                $query->where($db->quoteName('a.gender') . ' = ' . $db->quote('others'));
            }

            //Language
            $query->where('a.language in (' . $db->quote(Factory::getLanguage()->getTag()) . ',' . $db->quote('*') . ')');
            //Access
            $query->where($db->quoteName('a.access') . " IN (" . implode(',', Factory::getUser()->getAuthorisedViewLevels()) . ")");
        } else {
            $query->order($db->quoteName('a.ordering') . ' DESC');
        }

        return $query;
    }

    /**
     * get total celebrity
     *
     * @return mixed
     */
    public static function getCountCelebrities()
    {
        $db = Factory::getDbo();
        $query = $db->getQuery(true);
        $query->select(array('COUNT(a.id) as total_celebrities'));
        $query->from($db->quoteName('#__avisamoviedb_celebrities', 'a'));
        $query->where($db->quoteName('a.published') . " = " . $db->quote('1'));
        $db->setQuery($query);
        return $db->loadObject();
    }
}
```

And this code to **site/view/celebrities/view.html.php**:

```
class AvisamoviedbViewCelebrities extends HtmlView
{

    protected $items;
    protected $pagination;

    /**
     * Display the view
     *
     * @param   string    The name of the template file to parse; automatically searches through the template paths.
     *
     * @return  mixed  A string if successful, otherwise an Error object.
     */
    public function display($tpl = null)
    {
        $model = $this->getModel();
        $this->pagination  = $model->getPagination();
        $this->items = $model->getItems();

        $params = ComponentHelper::getParams('com_avisamoviedb');
        $this->columns = $params->get('celebrities_columns', 4);

        // Get model
        $this->total_celebrities = $model->getCountCelebrities()->total_celebrities ?? 0;
        $this->alphabets = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی'];

        foreach ($this->items as &$this->item) {
            $this->item->url = Route::_('index.php?option=com_avisamoviedb&view=celebrity&id=' . $this->item->id . ':' . $this->item->alias . AvisamoviedbHelper::getItemid('celebrities'));
        }

        return parent::display($tpl = null);
    }
}
```

And this one to **site/view/celebrities/tmpl/default.php**:

```
use Joomla\CMS\Factory;
use Joomla\CMS\Language\Text;
use Joomla\CMS\Router\Route;
use Joomla\CMS\Uri\Uri;

$input = Factory::getApplication()->input;
$Itemid = $input->get('Itemid', 0, 'INT');
$alphaindex = $input->get('alphaindex', 'all', 'WORD');

$allAlphaUrl = 'index.php?option=com_avisamoviedb&view=celebrities&Itemid=' . $Itemid;

if ($alphaindex) {
    $alphaUrl = 'index.php?option=com_avisamoviedb&view=celebrities&alphaindex=' . $alphaindex . '&Itemid=' . $Itemid;
} else {
    $alphaUrl = 'index.php?option=com_avisamoviedb&view=celebrities&Itemid=' . $Itemid;
}

?>

<div id="com-avisa-moviedb" class="avisamoviedb avisa-moviedb avisa-moviedb-view-celebrities">

    <div class="moviedb-filters">
        <div class="pull-left">
            <ul>
                <li class="<?php echo ($alphaindex == 'all') ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                    <a href="<?php echo Route::_($allAlphaUrl); ?>"><?php echo Text::_('COM_AVISAMOVIEDB_ALL'); ?></a>
                </li>
                <?php foreach ($this->alphabets as $alphabet) { ?>
                    <li class="<?php echo ($alphaindex == $alphabet) ? 'active' : ''; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo Route::_($alphaUrl . '&alphaindex=' . $alphabet); ?>">
                            <?php echo $alphabet; ?>
                        </a>
                    </li>
                <?php } ?>
            </ul>
        </div>
        <div class="pull-right">
            <?php echo Text::_('COM_AVISAMOVIEDB_TOTAL'); ?>:
            <strong><?php echo $this->total_celebrities; ?></strong>
        </div>
    </div>

    <?php if (!count($this->items)) { ?>
        <div class="alert alert-warning">
            <?php echo Text::_('COM_AVISAMOVIEDB_NOTHING_FOUND'); ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php foreach (array_chunk($this->items, $this->columns) as $this->items) { ?>
        <div class="avisamoviedb-row">
            <?php foreach ($this->items as $celebrity) { ?>
                <div class="item avisamoviedb-col-sm-<?php echo round(12 / $this->columns); ?>">
                    <div class="celebritie-poster">
                        <img src="<?php echo Uri::root() . $celebrity->profile_image; ?>" alt="<?php echo $celebrity->title; ?>">
                        <a href="<?php echo $celebrity->url; ?>" class="play-icon"><i class="avisamoviedb-icon-celebrities"></i></a>
                    </div>
                    <div class="celebritie-details">
                        <div class="celebritie-name">
                            <a href="<?php echo $celebrity->url; ?>">
                                <h4 class="celebritie-title"><?php echo $celebrity->title; ?></h4>
                            </a>
                            <span><?php echo $celebrity->designation; ?></span>
                        </div>
                    </div>
                </div>
            <?php } ?>
        </div>
    <?php } ?>

    <?php
        if ($this->pagination->pagesTotal > 1) { ?>
        <?php echo $this->pagination->getPagesLinks(); ?>
    <?php } ?>

</div>
```

But this code doesn’t filter my celebrities in my site.
What’s wrong?

[image: Check example]

Here you can see I choose 'ص', but I can see all items.
All these items must hide... And if I choose the right alphabet, these items must show.
This code must work as some filter.

Answer (score 4, accepted):

Per documentation, `WORD` filter does not allow unicode characters:

> WORD: A string containing A-Z or underscores only (not case sensitive)

https://api.joomla.org/framework-2/classes/Joomla-Filter-InputFilter.html

You may need to get unfiltered input using `RAW` filter and filter it yourself using a suitable regular expression. Since you already have a list of allowed values, you can use `in_array()` instead to determine whether input value is valid:

```
$characters = ['ا', 'ب', 'پ', 'ت', 'ث', 'ج', 'چ', 'ح', 'خ', 'د', 'ذ', 'ر', 'ز', 'ژ', 'س', 'ش', 'ص', 'ض', 'ط', 'ظ', 'ع', 'غ', 'ف', 'ق', 'ک', 'گ', 'ل', 'م', 'ن', 'و', 'ه', 'ی'];
$alphaindex = $inputs->get('alphaindex', '', 'RAW');

if (in_array($alphaindex, $characters, true))
{
    $query->where($db->quoteName('a.title') . " LIKE " . $db->quote(($alphaindex) . '%'));
}
```

Comment: ...and this is why we should always ask Joomla question on JSE [instead of Stack Overflow](https://stackoverflow.com/q/77255419/2943403).

Comment: @mickmackusa u ask me ask here and i have not permision delete my question from SOF ...

Comment: The SO moderators have appropriately deleted the cross-posted question.  Your permission is not required for such Stack Exchange Network housekeeping.  You expect this kind of outcome if you cross-post in the future, @Ali.